# Set the placeholder text colour of a UISearchField in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios13

I'm trying to set the placeholder text colour of a UISearchField in iOS 13 (beta).

My code worked in iOS 12 and before. I can still change the UISearchField background colour, the colour of the search icon, and so on...

Here's what I'm trying:

```swift
searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
  string: "My placeholder text",
  attributes: [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red
  ]
);
```

I expect the placeholder text to now be red, but it remains grey.

Comment: By the way you code works fine. Seems that your problem is in another point. probably you don't call this code

Comment: @dmitry: none of the suggestions in that thread (almost all of which are identical to the above) work in iOS 13. The code is being called and I'm using a minimal example. If it's working for you, perhaps you're not using iOS 13.

Comment: probably you are right. I used iOS 12.2 to test

Comment: Well, as the title and the post itself say, this issue affects iOS 13 only.

Comment: @Matt Any update on this question? I didn't find any answer either, this is triggering. How hard it is to just change a text color on the placeHolder. This is because of Dark/Light mode, I don't want the system to override it.

Comment: @Funnycuni I'm afraid I didn't find an answer. We had to change our app's UX to accommodate the colour we can't change...

Comment: **Check this for Xcode11 and iOS 13 :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/58375484/7851805

Comment: @Nick that answer uses setValue(_, forKey:), which is a private API the use of which can get one banned from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSMutableAttributeString as below,

```
  let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "your placeHolder")

    attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))

searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = attrString
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference for me. And should we expect it to?-- the mutability of the attributed string doesn't seem to matter here.